# swift reading integer quesiton

Tags: swift, integer, swift4

I'm new to swift programming. I compile my programs in windows or online compiler. I stucked reading an integer in swift. I succesfully read integer from console. But I can't use this integer variable in a while loop. How can I use integer variable in while loop that read from console?
my attempt is:

```
import Foundation

print("Enter a number:")


let inputNumber = Int(readLine()!)
if let inputNumber = inputNumber {
    print(inputNumber)
}


if inputNumber == 3 {
    print("number = 3") }
    else { print("number != 3") }

var sayi = inputNumber  
if sayi == 3 {
    print("sayi = 3") }
    else { print("sayi != 3") }
    
while sayi > 0 {
        print("*", terminator:"")
        sayi = sayi - 1 }
```

compile errors are:

main.swift:21:12: error: binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'

while sayi > 0 {
~~~~ ^ ~

main.swift:21:12: note: overloads for '>' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Self, Self), (Self, Other)

while sayi > 0 {
^

main.swift:23:16: error: value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
sayi = sayi - 1

Comment: Your code is imcomplete (missing curly braces). What do you mean by "can't use this in a while loop"? Do you get a compiler error, or what happens?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen my loop isn't incomplete. I added all the compile errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inputNumber and sayi are optional values and the compiler consider `Int` and `Int?` to be different types that it can't compare

I would use the following logic to read and convert the user input

```
let inputNumber: Int
//The below if clause will be successful only if both deadline() and Int() returns non-nil values
if let input = readLine(), let value = Int(input) { 
    inputNumber = value
} else {
    print("Bad input")
    inputNumber = 0
}
```

and then the rest of the code will work (here I simplified it somewhat)

```
var sayi = inputNumber

sayi == 3 ? print("sayi = 3") : print("sayi != 3")

while sayi > 0 {
    print("*", terminator:"")
    sayi -= 1
}
```

Comment: I run your code but there is no * printing. Why ıt can't happen?

Comment: @crazycomputer, I have no idea it works fine for me. Does it print anything?

Comment: it print :                                                                                                          "3
sayi = 3
***Press any key to continue . . ."

Comment: So then it works, it prints 3 stars. Maybe you should add an empty print after the loop to get a new line